# How to unset a field from all documents with php mongo adapter?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the task to `$unset` some fields from a collection, what i am trying to do :

```
     $collection->update(
            array(
                'field' => array('$exists' => true),
            ),
            array(
                '$unset' => array(
                    'field' => '',
                )
            ),
            array(
                'multi' => true
            )
        );
```

In xdebug i am getting: `$collection: {w => 1, wtimeout => 10000}` but when i check database nothing was changed my field is there untouched.

Comment: Code here looks okay. Is your actual query possibly on a nested field with "dot notation"?

Comment: Have you tried setting the value to a boolean like for example `array('$unset' => array('field' => true))`?

Comment: @user3561036 some of the fields are embeded, others are references but i do not use in my query dot notation

Comment: @chridam i tried with boolean value still nothing, i guess there are issues with php mongo adapter

Comment: What I'm **really** trying to tell you is that there is nothing wrong with the "field" as you have typed it here, but your **real code** that you are not showing here likely has problems by doing things that are not allowed. That's the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue:
Actually the parameter for `multi` in php is `multiple`, i didn't count the responses and didn't see that it was unset-ing just one document.

```
 $collection->update(
        array(
            'field' => array('$exists' => true),
        ),
        array(
            '$unset' => array(
                'field' => '',
            )
        ),
        array(
            'multiple' => true
        )
    );
```